# Unable to execute postgres sql script from ansible

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I want to execute a postgresql sql which is fetched from my git resource.
I want to first fetch all the scripts from git repository and then wants to execute scripts from a particular directory which i taking as an input in ansible script.This is my complete ansible script

```
- hosts: "{{ HOST }}"
  become: true
  become_user: "admin"
  become_method: su
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    app_path: "{{ app_path }}"
    app_dir: "{{ app_dir }}"

  tasks:
    - stat:
        path: "{{ app_path }}/{{ app_dir }}"
      register: exist

    - name: create "{{ app_path }}/{{ app_dir }}" directory
      file: dest="{{ app_path }}/{{ app_dir }}" state=directory 
      when: exist.stat.exists != True


    - git: 
        repo: http://git-url/postgres-demo.git
        dest: "{{ app_path }}/{{ app_dir }}"
        version: "{{ GIT_TAG }}"
        refspec: '+refs/heads/{{ GIT_TAG }}:refs/remotes/origin/{{ GIT_TAG }}'
        update: yes
        force: true
      register: cloned  

    - name: Execute postgres dump files
      shell: "/usr/bin/psql -qAtw -f  {{ item }}"
      with_fileglob:
          - "{{ app_path }}/{{ app_dir }}/{{ scripts_dir }}/*"
      register: postgres_sql
      become: true
      become_user: "postgres"
      become_method: su
```

Above script is executed successfully but postgres step throwing me following waning:

```
[WARNING]: Unable to find '/home/admin/postgres-dev/test' in expected paths.
```

When i checked my postgresql db,I don't find the table that i want to create using this scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All lookups in Ansible are executed on **local** ansible host.

So:

```
with_fileglob:
  - "{{ app_path }}/{{ app_dir }}/{{ scripts_dir }}/*"
```

uses `fileglob` lookup, which searches files on localhost!

You should refactor this code to use `find` module first to find all required scripts, register its output and then loop with `with_items` over registered variable to execute scripts.